# using function in ternary operator .net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ternary-operator

I am puzzled with using function in ternary operator in MVC4.

Here is what I have condition-

```
@(Session["LanguageCode"]!=null? GetLanguage(Users):"Users")
```

where `Session["LanguageCode"]` is language code coming through session.

I want to get word's meaning  through ajax call if this works-

```
<script>
function GetLanguage(Users){
//some ajax call on method.
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is "Users" in GetLanguage(Users) call...???

Comment: ...what do you really want to do over here??

Comment: This makes no sense. First: You cant use js in c# code. Razor is evaluated by the server when generating the view but javascript is evaluated by the client. Second: What would be the point? - just evaluate and set the value in your controller method.